# Как правильно загружать огромные уровни в unity?

Tags: unity3d, 2d

Как правильно загружать огромные уровни в unity?

Определенную инфу довольно трудно найти в поисковике. Но лично я думаю, что это делается так:
Сначала загружается весь уровень целиком, затем он делится на какие-то условные блоки, затем все блоки, кроме того где персонаж, выгружаются из памяти и подгружаются по мере приближения к следующему блоку, в общем получается так, что в памяти находятся только то, что используется в данный момент. Я правильно понимаю принцип? Если да, то как конкретно это делается в unity? Расставлять коллайдеры и при вхождении в них подгружать эти блоки? Как-то не элегантно? Как по мне так вообще должно быть какое-то готовое решение(в asset store хотя бы), так как в большинстве игр есть такая подгрузка.

Кто знает как решать этот вопрос?

Comment: у тебя разнЯтся заголовок и тело вопроса..... если смотреть на тело, то тебе судя по всему нужно искать по словам Camera occlusion culling...... Суть в том, что она не рендерит то, что она не видит в данный момент ...... https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html  ...... ну и это https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/UnderstandingFrustum.html до кучи

Comment: Ещё рекомендую почитать про BSP-деревья и Octo-деревья

Answer (score 0):

Загружать все в память, потом выгружать врядли понадобиться. Почитай про пространственное разбиение в играх, например вот(правда на примере поиска ближайшего врага, но суть таже) http://live13.livejournal.com/475266.html   В маинкрафт, например,  используются так называемые чанки( блоки 16х16), а видимость кол-ва этих чанков обусловливается сеткой (2n-1)x(2n-1), n>2. Суть в том, что главный герой находится в локальной матрице 9х9 например, в центральной ячейке (1,1) , и отрисовываются только остальные 8 ячеек матрицы. Как  только он покидает границу ячейки, проиходит перерасчет локальной матрицы. В играх с ассиметричной геометрией скорей всего придется использовать ячейки разного размера. Делают еще две матрицы одна определяет видимость, вторая побольше именно подгрузку блоков( в unity можно инстанцировать префабы через асинхронную загрузку). Размеры задают в зависимости, например, от максимальной скорости смещения персонажа. Зависимость также от камеры может быть. Динамические элементы при удалении от них, например ты бросил авто, либо удаляютя, либо в пулл специальный складывается.  Нюансов много и все зависит от условий задачи(игры).